# What is the font used for Winter Bash 2016?

Tags: font-identification

I enjoy every year seeing what is designed for our [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/) but this year I'm having issues identifying what the font is used for the text **Winter Bash**:

[image: winter bash screenshot]

When I look for a solution with [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) the text seems to be causing an issue in the identifying process.  When I try to take the screenshot I have made of Winter Bash and use [matcherator](https://www.fontspring.com/matcherator) to identify the font I run into the same issue.

Comment: Why the downvote??

Comment: Downvotes without comment don't help us learn…

Comment: @dlu I dont know why the poor love

Comment: @dlu  I guess some just dont like winter hats

Comment: Really cool you figured it out, IHMO!

Comment: I downvoted someone on Photo and had multiple people retaliate against me (I left a comment with what I didn't agree with). I understand why some prefer not commenting with their downvote as a result. I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Winter Bash**

The font is a modified [Heritage Font](https://creativemarket.com/dedemulyadi/908638-Heritage-Font-Combinations).  Here is an example:

[image]

Alternate letters were used on the **t** and **h**, then some freehand editing was done to complete the effect.

---

**2016**

The year is [Gotham](http://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham/overview/) with a thin outline added to give the rounded edges.

[image: Gotham Font]